# How to document dependencies between modules/libraries in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I know that Doxygen will generate pretty include graphs for you which show the dependencies between different files in a project.

However, in my project, certain sets of files are grouped together into what I will call "source code modules."  I am wondering, is there a way to have Doxygen generate a dependency graph for these higher-level modules?

For example, if I have the following code layout:

```
sources
|_ app
|_ liba
|_ libb
|_ libcommon
```

Where liba -> libcommon, libb -> libcommon, and app -> liba, app->libb (-> means "depends on").  I would like Doxygen to generate a graph showing these dependencies (which should look like a diamond).

Would I need to mark each source file in each module as belonging to a group (i.e., @defgroup)?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Doxygen has no knowledge about this information, at least when I understand your question. I think the best way would create a `dot` file that contains this information.

Comment: @albert I'm using version 1.8.16 of Doxygen.

Comment: It doesn't matter for this problem, but 1.8.16 is a bit older (August 8,2019) the current doxygen version is 1.9.8

Comment: @albert Understood.  Unfortunately, I have no control over which version is used; it's part of our CI/CD pipeline.